Tabular-style environment with automatic number of columns for given linewidth
I have a number of words that I want to fit into a grid in a way that each column aligns on the left and that the entire page width (or specified width, e.g., \linewidth) is utilized. However, I don't want to manually specify the number of columns.
I am looking for something that behaves like the bash command column or when you display the contents of a directory using ls and the output is longer than one line.

@Zarko, LaTeX can figure out how many words comfortably fit into one line, and where to break the line, including whether to break a word. This is done to optimally use the space available, without squishing or stretching any one line too much. I figured, my problem is a similar or at least related task.

You can put each word in a box of known size, then just let the usual line breaker split things up. Either explicitly using \makebox or as here looping through a space separated list.

\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{tabulate}{%
  \raggedright
  \xtabulate}
{\par}

\def\xtabulate#1 {\def\tmp{#1}%
  \ifx\tmp\xendtabulate\par\tmp
  \else
    \ifx\tmp\empty\else\noindent\makebox[6em][l]{#1} \fi
  \expandafter\xtabulate
\fi}
\def\xendtabulate{\end{tabulate}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabulate}
  This is a bunch of words that should be laid out in a grid tabulated
  so each word takes exactly 6em plus normal interword space.  This is
  a different bunch of words that should also be laid out in a grid
  tabulated so each word takes exactly 6em plus normal interword
  space.
\end{tabulate}

\end{document}


It's not fully fully automatic but this will certainly do. Didn't know you could loop like this through a "list". Got a working solution and learned more about LaTeX. Thank you!
